# Have nginx redirect everything to https except one directory

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

I need nginx to redirect all http URLs to https, with the exception a ".secret/" directory which should continue to be served as http.

So, for example:

- `http://example.com/a.html` --> `https://example.com/a.html`
- `http://example.org/z/b.html` --> `https://example.org/z/b.html`
- `http://example.com/.secret/x.html` --> `http://example.com/.secret/x.html`

I have the following in my configuration but for http, it returns addresses that include "_".

```
server {
    listen 80;
 
    server_name _;
 
    location /.secret {
        return http://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
 
    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Combining the comments from @mforsetti and @Pothi_Kalimuthu, the following worked:

```
server {
    listen 80;
 
    server_name _;
 
    location /.secret { }
 
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. You may leave the `.secret` location as empty for the desired response like `location /.secret {}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it returns addresses that include "_".

> ```
> server_name _;
>
> location /.secret {
>    return http://$server_name$request_uri;
> }
> ```

[`$server_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_name) returns assigned `server_name` to the `server` block, which in your case is `_`; hence the `_` in returned address.

If you want it to return a hostname or your `Host` request header, try using [`$host`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host), something like:

```
location /.secret {
    return http://$host$request_uri;
}
```

> `.secret/` directory which should continue to be served as http

if you want to serve a directory, specify a [`root`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directory.

```
location /.secret {
    root /path/to/your/parent/of/secret/directory;
}
```